# Solving Linear Equations with augmented matrices

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-system

Could someone please walk me through this question as I am struggling with it.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GILYf.png)

Comment: Nice. Did you try anything? The question's pretty clear and direct.

Answer (score 1):

Form the augmented coefficients matrix and begin reducing it by rows. Observe that I **already** interchanged rows 1 and 2:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&p&1&|&p\\
p&1&1&|&1\\
1&1&p&|&p^2\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&p&1&|&p\\
0&1-p^2&1-p&|&1-p^2\\
0&1-p&p-1&|&p^2-p\end{pmatrix}\;(**)$$

You can now check directly for $\;p=-1\;$ , and then for $\;p\neq-1\;$ you can add the second row multiplied by $\;-\cfrac1{1+p}\;$ to the third row and get::

$$(**)\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&p&1&|&p\\
0&1-p^2&1-p&|&1-p^2\\
0&0&(p+2)(p-1)&|&p^2-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Well, what can you see and deduce from up there?

Comment: Shouldn’t it read $(p-2)(p-1)$?

Comment: So what is the final value of p to make the model consistent? Apologies for my naivety